# iOS ODRefreshControll pull length

Tags: ios, objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

does anyone know how to reduce the amount of pulling you need to do in order to refresh for a ODRefreshControll? I've fiddled with the default settings but had no luck. There isn't much documentation on it. Has anyone had any success with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)dropViewDidBeginRefreshing:(ODRefreshControl *)refreshControl
{
    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        //ADD
        [self callMethod];

        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
});
}
```

Comment: The delay doesn't alter the amount of pulling you have to do